# Sum only positive/negative numbers whiting a range in Google Sheets

Tags: arrays, if-statement, google-sheets, range, google-sheets-formula

I'm gonna try to make it brief, but I have difficulty explaining exactly what I'm trying to accomplish. I'm currently trying to make a custom budget sheet. The formula shown in the image below looks at a bunch of numbers that fall under different categories.

[image: See Formula]

C16 is the category name, let's call it "Transfers".
The purple is the column holding different categories, one of them being "Transfers".
The teal is the column holding different values, some positive, some negative.

This way, it takes all the values that match up with the category C16 and sums it up. However, the values can both be positive **and** negative, and I'd like to split it into two different cells, one holding the positive sum, and one holding the negative sum.

Is this possible? Let me know if you require further information.

Answer (score 1):

cell **B2**:

```
=IF(A2="",, SUMIFS(E:E, D:D, A2, E:E, ">=0"))
```

cell **C2**:

```
=IF(A2="",, SUMIFS(E:E, D:D, A2, E:E, "<0"))
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 0):

For positive values

```
=sumif(range, ">0")
```

For negative values

```
=sumif(range, "<0")
```